Is the problem with the type I used to define rOffset, src and dst or is the jump instruction no longer working (if there is another method)
I tried this project about windows API hooking : https://cocomelonc.github.io/tutorial/2021/11/30/basic-hooking-1.html

At the first, everything was functioning properly, and I was receiving the three message boxes.
The main problem comes within the file hooking.cpp. Although the first/originql message box appears but after that the program ends without showing the second/hooked box.

So I tried some things like but it doesn't work :

I did put rOffset as a regular integer : DWORD rOffset; rOffset = dst-src;
I replaced memcpy() with CopyMemory().
I changed the patch type to BYTE : BYTE patch[5] = {0};
I attempted to change the type of both patch to void * and rOffset to const void*. However, I encountered errors due to the fact that the patch will receive bytes.
I don't know if the problem is with the number of bytes that need to be adjusted from 5 to a higher value.
I tried to x64dbg but I didn't know how to use it , if someone could help how to deal with memory processes in it and finding bugs.

// hooking logic
void setMySuperHook() {
  HINSTANCE hLib;
  VOID *myFuncAddress;
  DWORD *rOffset;
  DWORD src;
  DWORD dst;
  CHAR patch[5]= {0};

  // get memory address of function Cat
  hLib = LoadLibraryA("pet.dll");
  hookedAddress = GetProcAddress(hLib, "Cat");

  // save the first 5 bytes into originalBytes (buffer)
  ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID) hookedAddress, originalBytes, 5, NULL);

  // overwrite the first 5 bytes with a jump to myFunc
  myFuncAddress = &myFunc;

  // will jump from the next instruction (after our 5 byte jmp instruction)
  src = (DWORD)hookedAddress + 5;
  dst = (DWORD)myFuncAddress;
  rOffset = (DWORD *)(dst-src);

  // \xE9 - jump instruction
  memcpy(patch, "\xE9", 1);
  memcpy(patch + 1, &rOffset, 4);

  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)hookedAddress, patch, 5, NULL);

}

int main() {
// I delated some code here to get a small 
  // call original Cat function
  (catFunc)("meow-meow");

  // install hook
  setMySuperHook();

  // call Cat function after install hook
  (catFunc)("meow-meow");

}

If someone could help to understand the whole project , I have only few simple questions.

A DWORD has 32 bits while a void* likely contains 64 bits. Could be a problem.

Thanks @BoP for your reply , I can't define src and dst as void * neither patch , because the first are long integers and the second are bytes , I tried and still doesn't work
However , even with    VOID * rOffset;    I  am getting the same issue.
  I am currently  using Spotify and the command prompt simultaneously while running the program. I am unsure if this poses an issue, As  I think that the function GetCurrentProcess(); will return the process of Spotify. However, may I am not very understood the functionality of GetCurrentProcess in this context.

Some ideas: Are you using the same compiler as in the linked article? Especially the bitness of your binary (32 or 64) could be important. Try to step through with the debugger to find where it crashes.
